# Why are Clifford Algebras Superalgebras?

Tags: abstract-algebra, bilinear-form, clifford-algebras

In *Mathematical Gauge Theory With Applications to the Standard Model of Particle Physics* Hamilton on page 332 proves that Clifford algebras are superalgebras by the following:

First he defines two vector subspaces of the tensor algebra as

$$Cl^0(V,Q) = T^0(V)/(T^0(V)\cap I(Q))$$

$$Cl^1(V,Q) = T^0(V)/(T^1(V)\cap I(Q))$$

Then he states that because $$I(Q)= (T^0(V)\cap I(Q))\oplus(T^1(V)\cap I(Q))$$ it follows that $$CL(V,Q) = CL^0(V,Q)\oplus CL^1(V,Q)$$

I do not see why this is the case. Could someone explain this to me? It seems like I'm missing something trivial here.

Comment: Basically, the statement about $I(Q)$ is proving that it is a homogeneous ideal. Then the quotient is again a graded algebra. Have a look at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graded_ring#Graded_algebra

Answer (score 1):

Clifford algebras are superalgebras — i.e., they are $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded — because they can be expressed as a quotient of the tensor algebra by an ideal which is $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded.
There is a theorem which states a graded ideal results in a graded quotient algebra.
These main points are summarised below.

---

**Def.** An algebra $A$ is $R$-graded for a monoid $R$ (e.g., $\mathbb{Z}$ or $\mathbb{Z}_2$) if there is a decomposition
$$
A = \bigoplus_{k \in R} A_k
$$
which preserves multiplication,
$$
A_p A_q \subseteq A_{p + q}
\qquad\text{i.e.,}\qquad
a \in A_p \text{ and }b \in A_q \implies ab \in A_{p + q}
.$$

For example, the tensor algebra $V^\otimes = \bigoplus_{k=0}^\infty {V_{(1)} \otimes \cdots \otimes V_{(k)}}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-graded, since the tensor product of rank $p$ and $q$ tensors is rank $p + q$. In fact, $V^\otimes$ is $\mathbb{Z}_n$-graded for any $n$.

**Def.** An ideal $I \subseteq A$ of an $R$-graded algebra $A$ is itself *$R$-graded* (a.k.a. *homogeneous*) if
$$
I = \bigoplus_{k \in R} I_k
\quad\text{where}\quad
I_k = I \cap A_k
.$$

For example, the ideal $I_{alt}$ of $V^\otimes$ generated by $\{a\otimes b + b\otimes a\}$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-graded, because $I_{alt} = I_{alt} \cap (V\otimes V)$.

**Thm.** If $A$ is an $R$-graded algebra, and $I$ is an $R$-graded ideal, then the quotient algebra $A/I$ is also $R$-graded.

For example, this implies $V^\otimes \big/ I_{alt} \cong \bigwedge V$ is $\mathbb{Z}$-graded.

On the other hand, a Clifford algebra is a quotient
$$
Cl(V, Q) = V^\otimes \big/ \langle a \otimes a - Q(a) \rangle
$$
by the ideal generated by $a\otimes a \sim Q(a)$.
This ideal is not $\mathbb{Z}$-graded. However, it is $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded (it is generated by the sum of a scalar and rank-$2$ tensor).
Since $V^\otimes$ is also $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded, the theorem above shows that $Cl(V, Q)$ is itself $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded (a.k.a., a superalgebra).

---

Proofs can be found e.g., in my [unpublished thesis](https://jollywatt.github.io/assets/pdf/2022.Geometric-Algebra-for-Special-Relativity-and-Manifold-Geometry.pdf), where I copied these from.